# why Jenkins shell script hangs when i run sudo pm2 ls

Tags: bash, jenkins, sudo, pm2

I confess I am total newbie to Jenkins.
I have

> Jenkins-tls

installed on my Mac for experimentation.
I have a remote server that I testing with.
My Jenkins script is ultra simple.

```
ssh to the remote machine
sudo pm2 ls
```

the last command just hangs

I run the same 2 commands from the command line and it all works perfectly.
FYI, I need sudo for pm2 since I need to be root to run pm2, without sudo, I get access denied.

Any thoughts?

Comment: does sudo require you to type a password?

Comment: not when I am in  shell and logged on to that machine. When I run it from Jenkins, I am running Jenkings from a shell and not a service, I see that it is asking for a password. So this is a big clue

Comment: Do you expect the `sudo pm2 ls` to be executed on the remote machine? Because it is not. When you type the two commands sequentially, the sudo is executed on the remote machine, but any commands in jenkins are executed synchronously, i.e. the sudo is run *after ssh returns* (e.g. when the remote session is terminated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you make the invalid assumption that jenkins somehow "types" commands after starting ssh to the remote session's command shell. This is not what happens. Instead, it will wait for the ssh command to finish, and only then execute the next command `sudo pm2 ls`. This never happens, because the ssh session never terminates. You observe this as a "hang".

How to solve this?

If there's only a small number of commands, you can use ssh to run them with

```
ssh user@remote sudo mp2 ls
ssh user@remote command arg1 arg2
```

If this gets longer, why not place all commands in a remote script and just run it with

```
ssh user@remote /path/to/script
```